# Python Sorting matrix rows into row-echelon...sort of

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to write a custom sorting function for a two-dimensional array in Python 3.5. The idea is to turn an array into a semi-row-echelon form where any row with a leading 1 moves to the top of the other rows, anything with leading 0's to the bottom, and the rest sorted in between. You can see the example matrices below.

```
before = [
   [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
   [0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 4],
   [0, 0, 2, 2, -1, 3],
   [1, 2, 5, -2, 4, -3],
   [2, 1, 1, -1, 4, 2],
   [0, 0, 1, 4, 5, -1]
]

after = [
    [1, 2, 5, -2, 4, -3],
    [2, 1, 1, -1, 4, 2],
    [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 4],
    [0, 0, 1, 4, 5, -1],
    [0, 0, 2, 2, -1, 3]
]
```

If I were doing this in Java, I would write a Comparator object or a compareTo method. But looking online, in Python 3+ it doesn't seem like the pythonic way to use cmp parameter when sorting anymore.

Right now I can use

```
for i in range(len(mat)-1, -1, -1):
    mat.sort(key=itemgetter(i), reverse=True)
```

to do this, but this doesn't move the rows whose first nonzero value is 1 to the top.

I'd appreciate any suggestions anyone might have to do this in the most pythonic way. Also, if anyone has any good resources on learning the proper pythonic way of doing other things, I'd appreciate that. I sometimes do things as though I'm writing them in other languages and don't realize that Python has a preferred way of doing it (I'm looking at you, list comprehensions).

Comment: This github gist is pretty cool about doing things in a 'pythonic' way. [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/6213790)

Comment: @eugenhu "pythonic" is very subjective, be careful how you use that word, even if you put it in quotes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah I don't really know what it means I just hear it thrown around a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
mat.sort(key=lambda l: [
    (0, 0) if x == 1 else
    (2, 0) if x == 0 else
    (1, x)     for x in l
])
```

And take advantage of the fact that tuples and lists are compared lexicographically, first two elements are compared and so on.

---

Edit:

I change my opinion, I think doing it as shown above might be the better way compared to creating a comparison function (which isn't that much clearer), and quicker as well.

Test code:

```
TRIALS = 10000

mat = [
   [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
   [0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 4],
   [0, 0, 2, 2, -1, 3],
   [1, 2, 5, -2, 4, -3],
   [2, 1, 1, -1, 4, 2],
   [0, 0, 1, 4, 5, -1]
]

@functools.cmp_to_key
def matcmp(a, b):
    for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
        if (ai == bi): continue

        if (0 != ai != 1 and 0 != bi != 1):
            return a < b
        elif (ai == 1 or bi == 0):
            return -1
        else:
            return  1
    else:
        return 0

start = time.time()    

for i in range(TRIALS):
    sorted(mat, key=matcmp)

print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()

for i in range(TRIALS):
    sorted(mat, key=lambda l: [
        (0, 0) if x == 1 else
        (2, 0) if x == 0 else
        (1, x)     for x in l
    ])

print(time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
0.10232377052307129
0.09116077423095703
```

Comment: Thanks, the first algorithm worked. I had to swap the 1 and 2 on lines 3 and 4 to get the right order, but it seemed to work.

Comment: @BrentParker Oh yeah sorry, you need to swap the 0 and x as well, I've made an edit.